# Sidewalk and grassy dirt?

Tags: modifiers, workflow

So, I think I actually "get" blender pretty well, I want to know from a workflow approach, how would I make a sidewalk, with lumpy ground underneath it. I want the sidewalk to look like it is pressing the dirt away, and the grass growing on my dirt should not be poking out through the "solid sidewalk" right now I have them as two separate objects, one named "sidewalk" the other "dirt" since they are both very different materials I assumed they need to be two different objects.

Generally the thing I'm looking for would also apply to how to make animal tracks in snow, tire tracks in sand, etc... if you guys could just point me in the right direction, I don't mind doing my research, I just don't know where to even start.  Oh, also, I can't shrinkwrap my sidewalk to the land, that would cause the sidewalk to be lumpy on top.

### update

So, lol I just tried to apply the sidewalk as a shrinkwrap to the ground then I added the sidewalk to a vertex group, assign, selected only the top of the sidewalk vertexes and removed them from the group....That worked pretty well, now if I could get the particles to stop "coming through"

Here's what I want, the only comment I got seemed to focused on a very specific situation, as I said, this question applies to any situation where one surface should be "disturbed" by another.  Here are images like I am describing
[image]

[image]

Comment: The workflow I would use would depend upon the end use for the sidewalk and the dirt? My answer will be different if the end use is for a game, than if it for a stationary render. What is the surface of the sidewalk—concrete, bricks, or gravel? Again, my suggestion would depend upon the answer to this question. And what is the grass surface like? I'd take one approach for a well maintained lawn, another approach if the sidewalk and lawn are in a setting of urban decay, and still other techniques in other situations.

Comment: Please include an image of something similar to your artistic vision and a render or screen capture of what you have completed.  Your descriptions are difficult to read.  You wrote .... make a sidewalk, with lumpy grass under it. Do you mean sidewalk with grass on the sides?  I am trying to distinguish between [under] and [on the sides].

Comment: honestly you better go for one single mesh and use masks

Comment: ah! aha! @Yvain I could use a mask then invert copy the mesh to another object! that way I'd have both halves of the mold! good thinking I'll try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you subdivide a plane, unwrap it, and paint a MASK as the one you can see here, you will be able to use it with a displace modifier, also use it to control the particles emission, and finally to split two materials with a mix slot.So that the object is one. Cheers.

[image]

Comment: YES! this is what I wanted! Now I can go google what all that means. Knowing what a hammer is is easy! it's knowing when to use it! that's what you provided thanks!

Comment: One question, could you let me know what's in those node groups?

Comment: The node going to the mix shader is an Add shader on which are connected a diffuse and a glossy material. The one going to the displace is a color mix using two different noise textures, the mask is connected to the factor slot. ;)